# My min(list) function is producing the wrong output and I do not know why

Tags: python

I am running a very basic program to find the min/max value of a list I generated, and I am getting the wrong output, but do not know why. I am attaching screenshots which show the output. Although the list is not fully shown due to its length, enough is shown to show that my min and max functions are wrong. The code is also included. [Output of my min/max functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guSQS.png)

```
print("Welcome to EPA Mileage Calculator")
yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
while yearChoice != 2008 and yearChoice != 2009:
    print("Invalid input, please try again")
    yearChoice = int(input("What year would you like to view data for? (2008 or 2009): "))
saveResults = input("Enter the filename to to save results to: ")

if yearChoice == 2008:
    fileIn = open("epaVehicleData2008.csv", "r")
    fileIn.readline()
    minMPG = []
    maxMPG = []
    for line in fileIn:
        line = line.strip()
        dataList = line.split(",")
        if dataList[0] not in ['VANS - PASSENGER TYPE', 'VANS - CARGO TYPE', 'TRUCK', 'MINIVAN - 4WD', 'MINIVAN - 2WD']:
            minMPG.append(dataList[8])
            #print(minMPG)
            maxMPG.append(dataList[8])
            #print(maxMPG)
    print(minMPG)
    print(min(minMPG))
    print(maxMPG)
    print(max(maxMPG))
```

Comment: Please provide the output of your code as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using strings.

Firstly, change the strings into integers.
 Use:`minMPG.append(int(dataList[8]))`.

Same for `maxMPG.append(int(dataList[8]))`

This should work.

Comment: It's not that simple; `line` does not contain only values convertible to `int`.

Comment: Yes. So it should convert dataList[8] to int . Hope now it's correct!